How to Handle SEO for Client-Side Components in Next.js which has Text Content for Search Engine Ranking?
I am building a Next.js application where I have a single common audio file and multiple text components. Each text component corresponds to a specific timestamp in the audio file. The text components need to update their state to maintain isActive status, and they should highlight when the audio reaches their respective timestamps.
I am using useState to manage the isPlaying state for each text component, which makes them client components declared with use client;.
My concern is that making these components client-side will impact SEO, as search engines might not index the text content properly.
Here is a simplified code example
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const textComponents = [
  { id: 1, text: "First part of the text.", start: 0, end: 5 },
  { id: 2, text: "Second part of the text.", start: 5, end: 10 },
  { id: 3, text: "Third part of the text.", start: 10, end: 15 },
];

const Home = ({ textComponents }) => {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const audioElement = new Audio('/audio/sample.mp3');
    setAudio(audioElement);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (audioElement && isPlaying) {
        setCurrentTime(audioElement.currentTime);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [isPlaying, audio]);

  const handlePlayPause = () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audio.pause();
    } else {
      audio.play();
    }
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handlePlayPause}>
        {isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
      </button>
      <div>
        {textComponents.map(component => (
          <TextComponent
            key={component.id}
            component={component}
            currentTime={currentTime}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const TextComponent = ({ component, currentTime }) => {
  const isActive = currentTime >= component.start && currentTime <= component.end;

  return (
    <p style={{ color: isActive ? 'red' : 'black' }}>
      {component.text}
    </p>
  );
};

export default Home;

Both these components need to be marked with use client;.
In addition to highlighting text, there are other scenarios where I need to use hooks, necessitating the use of client components.
How can I ensure that my webpage ranks well in search engines while maintaining the required client-side functionality for synchronizing text with the audio?

If you're able to rewrite your clientside logic without using useState. The following might help.
Try adding all your client side logic inside an if condition which validates true only on client side.
if(typeof window !== undefined){

// your client side logic to handle the rendering of text component
//This runs on the browser and updates the child

}else{

//your normal SSG logic
//This runs during build time and the static site is served first

}

Here the initial HTML will have all the static text elements whereas you can make things dynamic after serving.

This will be still using ‘use client’? The else part will run in server before being served to client?
